# Why is it possible to define a potential difference in a wire that carries a steady current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current

My book introduces $\nabla\times E = 0$ as the condition for an electrostatic field, which is what makes it possible to define a potential difference between two points. As far as my present understanding goes, this happens when there are no charges are moving around.

So in a wire carrying a steady current, why is it that it's still possible to define a potential difference between two points in the wire even though there are charges moving around? In other words, why is it that $\nabla\times E = 0$ is apparently true inside the wire?

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell's equation tells us that for the general case
$$
\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}
$$
This vanishes not only when charges are stationary, but also when they are moving in a uniform continuous manner such as to produce a constant magnetic field (which describes your example). Another general case is when the charges vary over a finite range then we average and obtain that the derivative of the average vanishes as it should for any quantity that varied over a finite range so that $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{\left\langle E\right\rangle}=0$.